# MySQL. Как происходит получение максимального/минимального значения?

Tags: mysql

Всем доброго времени суток!

С коллегами небольшой спор произошел по скорости выполнения(и как следствие по оптимальности работы) следующей задачи:

Необходимо из БД вытащить записи (от 1 до 5*10^6) используя фильтр. Найти минимальный, максимальный элемент. Зная минимальный, с шагом в N записей пройтись по всем записям (естественно попавшим под фильтр) до максимального. После каждой порционной выборки выполняем необходимые действия с полученными записями.

Решений видим два:

1. Получаем минимальный (1 запрос), максимальный(1 запрос). Зная минимальный и используя Limit  и Offset, пробегаемся до максимального (x запросов)
2. Получаем все записи, попавшие под фильтр(1 запрос). На бэке уже разбиваем полученный массив на подмассивы, и работаем с каждой порцией записей.

Спорный момент в скорости выполнения всей задачи и нагрузке на мускуль.
Решающие моменты:

1. когда получаем минимальный/максимальный элемент - мы делаем выборки по всем записям, сортируем и берём первый?
2. Если брать сразу все записи, попавшие под фильтр - может "задуматься" мускуль( т.к. возвращать придется в худшем случае 5*10^6 записей и более)
3. Всё осложняется тем, что могут быть LEFT JOIN-ы.

Где лучше почитать о том, работает mysql: создание временным таблиц и т.д.

Comment: так вы запросы профилируйте и смотрите. Поиск max/min может быть как очень быстрым, так и очень медленным - все зависит от построенных запросов. Из книжек можно почитать [эту](http://www.highperfmysql.com/).

Comment: Есть ли вообще смысл получать все записи? Что с ними происходит в последствии? Если какая-то агрегация, анализ, может быть лучше написать один-два корректных запроса? JOIN при правильно построенных индексах не слишком осложняет жизнь. :)

Comment: Как и всегда, все зависит от конкретной ситуации. Так что было бы неплохо увидеть пример запроса и код ваших действий с данными.